# Python dictionary modification

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

This is a python code

```
def build_person(first_name, last_name, age=None):     
Return a dictionary of information about a person.
   person = {'first': first_name, 'last': last_name}     
   if age:         
      person['age'] = age     
   return person
```

I understand everything but the line

```
person['age'] = age
```

Because, "person" is a dictionary, and so if I want to modify it, shouldn't it accept a key-value pair? How can I modify it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, person[age] = age
works only when age is given as argument when calling this function.

person is dictionary, age in person[age] is key, and the age which is at right side of assignment operator(=) is value passed as argument in function.

for e.g :
for the given code below in last line i have given age as argument.

```
def build_person(first_name, last_name, age=None):     

   person = {'first': first_name, 'last': last_name}     
   if age:         
      person['age'] = age  
   print(person)   
   return person
build_person("yash","verma",9)
```

Output for above code is :

```
{'first': 'yash', 'last': 'verma', 'age': 9}
```

now,
if i don't give age as a argument then,

```
def build_person(first_name, last_name, age=None):     

    person = {'first': first_name, 'last': last_name}     
    if age:         
        person['age'] = age  
    print(person)   
    return person
build_person("yash","verma")
```

output will be:

```
{'first': 'yash', 'last': 'verma'}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I've understood correctly: In the line (person['age'] = age) the first 'age' is the third key of the dictionary (if any, following the 'if' block), while the second age is the value coming from the function calling, and this age becomes the third value of the dictionary called 'person'. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

```
person['age'] = age
```

The 'age' inside the brackets is the key, the value 'age' is where your value is assigned.
The person dictionnary becomes:

```
 {'first': first_name, 'last': last_name,'age': age}
```